# how to partialy drop functools.lru_cache by one argument?

Tags: python, caching

I have a `get(bid, mid, pid)` function. It is decorated with `lru_cache`. I want to drop all cache entries with `bid == 105`, for example.

I was thinking of some closures, that return decorated functions. Then I get some separate caches for each `bid` entry, and non cached function with dict of these closures that acts like a router. but maybe there is a more pythonic way for this?

upd: i came up with somthing like this, and it seems to work

```
getters = {}
def facade(bid, mid, pid):
    global getters             # not very good, better to use class

    if not bid in getters:
        def create_getter(bid):
            @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
            def get(mid, pid):
                print ('cache miss')
                return bid + mid + pid
            return get
        getters[bid] = create_getter(bid)

    return getters[bid](mid, pid)

val = facade(bid, mid, pid)   # ability to read like before
if need_to_drop:
    getters[bid].cache_clear()  # ability to flush entries with specified bid
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap `functools.lru_cache` and filter parameters?

```py
from functools import lru_cache


def filtered_lru(filter_func: callable, maxsize: int):
    def wrapper(f):
        cached = lru_cache(maxsize=maxsize)(f)

        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if filter_func(*args, **kwargs):
                print('Using cache')
                return cached(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                print('Not using cache')
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped

    return wrapper


def _get_filter(*args, **kwargs):
    return args[0] != 0


@filtered_lru(_get_filter, maxsize=100)
def get(num):
    print('Calculating...')
    return 2 * num


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get(1))
    print(get(1))
    print(get(1))
    print(get(0))
    print(get(0))
```

output:

```
Using cache
Calculating...
2
Using cache
2
Using cache
2
Not using cache
Calculating...
0
Not using cache
Calculating...
0
```

Comment: cool stuff. it just do not cache some values on filter condition, right?